# How to fix the positioning of scroll bar using css

Tags: html, css

I have a table:- HTML Code

```
<div class="table-scroll">
      <table class="my-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>firstName</th>
            <th>lastName</th>
            <th>age</th>
            <th>email</th>  
            <th>balance</th>
            <th>Mode</th>
            <th>Total</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection" ng-class-even="'striped'">
            <td>{{row.Row1}}-{{row.Row2}}</td>
                <td>{{row.Row3 != null ? row.Row3 : "&nbsp;"}}</td>
                <td><div class="width">{{row.Row4 != null ? row.Row4 : "&nbsp;"}}</div></td>
                <td>{{row.Row5 != null ? (row.Row2 >= "50"? row.Row5 : (row.Row5 | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy')) : "&nbsp;"}}</td>
              <td>{{row.Row2}}</td>
              <td>{{row.Row5}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table> 
    </div>
```

CSS Code:-

```
.table-scroll {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  height:60vh;}

.width{
  width:50%;
}

.my-table {
  width: 100%; }

.my-table tbody tr {
    outline: none; }
.my-table tbody, thead {
    display: block; }
.my-table tbody{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    max-height:50vh;
}
.my-table  td {
  min-width: 90px;
  font-size: .7em;
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; }
.my-table th {
  min-width: 90px;
  background-color: #58595b;
  font-size: .7em;
  color: #ddd;
  padding: 6px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
  border-left: 1px solid #777;
  text-align: center;  }

.striped {
  background-color: #eeeff1; }
```

JS Code:-

```
angular.module('myApp', ['smart-table','lrDragNDrop'])
    .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout',
        function ($scope, $timeout) {

            var nameList = ['Pierre', 'Pol', 'Jacques', 'Robert', 'Elisa'];
            var familyName = ['Dupont', 'Germain', 'Delcourt', 'bjip', 'Menez'];

            $scope.isLoading = false;
            $scope.rowCollection = [];


            function createRandomItem() {
                var
                    firstName = nameList[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)],
                    lastName = familyName[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)],
                    age = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
                    email = firstName + lastName + '@whatever.com',
                    balance = Math.random() * 3000;

                return {
                    Row1: firstName,
                    Row2: lastName,
                    Row3: age,
                    Row4: email,
                    Row5: balance
                };
            }

            $scope.columns=['Row1','Row2','Row3','Row4','Row5'];

            for(var i=0;i<50;i++){
              $scope.rowCollection.push(createRandomItem());
            }



        }
    ]);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/YCXMSjAQ4VVSyvVFNLoI?p=preview

Here I am trying to fix the column headers and applying the vertical scroll to my `tbody`.
But the scroll appears at the very end when user scrolls through the horizontal scroll. I am trying to fix the position of vertical scroll but it changes my table look. Also, to achieve above I used `display:block` to tbody and thead but that ruins the alignment of columns. Can anybody please help me fixing the above issue.

Comment: You really should post your code here or users will be disinclined to help you.

Comment: You can achieve this by simply setting the width of your table to fill that of the container div.

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Answer (score -1):

```
.my-table tbody, thead {display: inline-block; }
.my-table th {min-width:92px;}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: you can use above css and try